# Do I need a Linux machine for back-end web development in PHP?

Tags: php, web, webserver, backend

I do not understand fully how might the operating system have anything to do with something deployed on the web if you are not hosting the site locally.

Also, if I do not have a Linux machine, can I replace it by running WSL on my Windows PC? Or are there some fatal drawbacks that might point to not doing that?

Comment: mostly servers out there are using linux os some of them use linux distros like ubuntu fedora etc. and I recommend you to use linux as it's more customizable than windows but you will need to learn a lot more about the servers security. Windows is heavy and has a term of lower security and firewall excepts you know very well of windows os.

Comment: @Mystogan With respect, your opinion (and that's all it is, an opinion, not facts) about the relative merits of Windows and Linux and their supposed levels of security is completely irrelevant to the question being asked.

Comment: @ADyson sorry I just too far already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can be installed and run on Windows and MacOS as well as Linux and others - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php for details.

Having said that, if you're planning to host the live site on a remote webserver which runs Linux, then developing that site on a machine which runs a similar operating system is likely to result in fewer unexpected compatibility issues when you deploy it to the live server. There are ways you can write the code in a cross-platform way (and 90+% of it isn't an issue anyway, there are just a few sticky areas mainly around files and paths etc), but there's always the danger of missing something.

If you prefer to develop mainly on Windows you could mitigate the above by having a virtual machine, or container, or by using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), where you run tests against the site in a comparable environment to its live environment before deploying it to live. There are other resources already available [such as this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/setup-a-php-development-environment-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-9193ff28ae83/) online which discuss the specifics of using PHP with WSL, if you want to pursue that.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can develop PHP fine in Windows or MacOS.

You will have to install the right tools though like a webserver (Apache, Microsoft IIS, etc).

I good starting point is to use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

No, you can do PHP development on any OS.
BTW I will suggest you to do learn linux in future.